# Design pattern: Dynamically display HTML / JS controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application where people can click on different categories and are then shown the corresponding order form dynamically and without a postback right after the items (with some fancy animations etc.), so it should be some kind of "one page style"

```
<div class="category" id="categoryIT">
   <div class="item" data-product="software">Software</div>
   <div class="item" data-product="notebooks">Notebooks</div>
   <div class="item" data-product="permissions">User permissions</div>

   <div class="orderView" style="display:none"></div>
</div>

<!-- templates -->

<div class="orderViewTemplate" id="templateSoftware">
   <!-- Inputs, sliders, accordions, etc -->
</div>
<div class="orderViewTemplate" id="templateNotebooks">
   <!-- Inputs, sliders, accordions, etc -->
</div>
<!-- etc -->
```

The order forms are consisting of quite a large amount of code, for example different accordions, sliders, inputs.

My first approach was to set the content of the orderView item to the content of some (invisible) templated orderForms

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function scrollto(element) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(element).offset().top) }, 'slow');
    };

    $(".item").on('click', function () {
        var product = $(this).data('product');
        var item = $(this);

        try {

            $(".orderView").fadeIn("slow", function () {
                item.closest('.category').find(".orderView").html($("#templateSoftware").html());
            });

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: item.closest('.category').find(".orderView").offset().top
            }, 'slow');

           // Initialize the JavaScript for the newly generated controls

        } catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    });


});
```

But that seems rather dirty, as the view will become huge as the number of categories/items grows. I think there must be a better way, I just don't really know one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can lax on the "no postbacks", I'd suggest having an AJAX call to get the content for each orderViewTemplate on the first time they are each accessed (or at some interval post-page load). This reduces your initial View page download size, and you can still cache or pre-cache the content for each orderViewTemplate at runtime client-side, getting you the UI experience partially back.

OR

Keep with the way you've got it and not worry about it until it becomes a problem. If this is early in the project, it's usually best to build first, optimize later. (Unless you're target platform is super-bandwidth-restricted)